# Unit testing forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing

I have designed a forms app which could have been better designed for unit testing by using business logic etc but at this stage I do not want to alter my code.  It is an app which performs steganography whereby a message is embedded in an image using an `LSB algorithm`. I am currently trying to write a unit test for the `button2 click event`. When `button2` is pressed; it will take text from two other `textboxes` and an image from a `picturebox` and run the `LSB algorithm`. Below is the test function.  I create test values for the `textboxes` concerned. When I run the test I get: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Does this refer to the `object sender = null;` `EventArgs e = null;`.  Or is what I am doing even possible?  Do I have to resort to `NUnitForms`?  I have added `button2_clic`k after the test function:

```
    public void button2_ClickTest()
    {
        StegApp_Accessor target = new StegApp_Accessor();
        // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        object sender = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        EventArgs e = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        target.textBox4.Text = "123456";
        target.textBox5.Text = "test message";
        target.button2_Click(sender, e);

        //Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot
        //  be    verified.");
        //target.textBox4.Text = "123456";
        //target.textBox5.Text = "test message";
        /*
        if (target.textBox4.Text.Length > 6 || target.textBox4.Text.Length < 0)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Key is out of range");
        }*/
        //Assert.IsInstanceOfType(target.b1,typeof(byte[]));
        if(target.b1.Length != target.temp4.Length)
        {
            Assert.Fail("B1 array does not have the correct lenght");
        }
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(target.image1,typeof(Bitmap));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(target.sb,typeof(StringBuilder));
        if(target.sb.Length != target.tmp3.Length)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Issue with Stringbuilder sb. Lenght not equal to 'tmp3'!");
        }
        Assert.Equals(target.z,target.StringLenght);
        Assert.Equals(target.c, target.textBox5.Text.Length);

    }
    `private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int x1, y1, z = 0;
        try
        {
            // Convert String Into Byte Array
            //byte[] sourceData = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a);
            // Convert Each Byte Into A Binary String
            //foreach (byte thisByte in sourceData)
            // binaryString.Append(Convert.ToString(thisByte, 2));
            while (!key)
            {
                if (textBox4.Text == "")
                {
                    //b1 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox5.Text);
                    key = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Error, enter your six digit key!");
                    return;
                }
                else if (textBox4.Text.Length > 6)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error, Key too long, try again!");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    //temp4 = textBox4.Text[0] + textBox4.Text[1] + textBox4.Text[2] + textBox4.Text[3] + textBox4.Text[4] + textBox4.Text[5] + textBox5.Text;
                    c = textBox5.Text.Length;
                    temp5 = c.ToString();
                    if (c <= 9)
                    {
                        temp5 = "000" + temp5;
                    }
                    else if (c <= 99)
                    {
                        temp5 = "00" + temp5;
                    }
                    else if (c <= 999)
                    {
                        temp5 = "0" + temp5;
                    }
                    else if (c <= 9999)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Message too long for this tool,try again");
                        return;
                    }
                    temp4 = textBox4.Text + temp5 + textBox5.Text;
                    b1 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(temp4);
                    key = true;
                }

            }
            //byte[] b1 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox5.Text);
            //b1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(a);
            //Create the array to be returned.
            tmp2 = new string[b1.Length];

            //Interate through each byte
            for (int i = 0; i < b1.Length; i++)
            {
                int x = b1[i];
                tmp = "";
                while (true)
                {
                    if ((x % 2) == 1)
                    {
                        tmp = "1" + tmp;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tmp = "0" + tmp;
                    }
                    x /= 2;
                    if (x < 1) break;
                }

                //Make sure the value is 8 chars long.
                tmp2[i] = tmp.PadLeft(8, '0');

            }
            //string a="";
            for (int i = 0; i < b1.Length; i++)
            {
                //a = tmp2[i];
                tmp3 = tmp3 + tmp2[i];
            }
            if (key)
            {
                tmp3 = "00" + tmp3;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp3 = "10" + tmp3;
            }


            sb.Append(tmp3);
            //temp5 = c.ToString();
            //z= c+1;
            StringLenght = sb.Length;
            byte Mask0 = 254;
            byte Mask1 = 1;
            byte NewRed = 0, NewGreen = 0, NewBlue = 0;
            // Loop through the images pixels to reset color.
            for (x1 = 0, y1 = 0; x1 < image1.Width && z < StringLenght; x1++)
            {
                for (y1 = 0; y1 < image1.Height && z < StringLenght; y1++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x1, y1);
                    //byte NewRed, NewGreen, NewBlue;
                    if (sb[z] == '0')
                    {
                        NewRed = Convert.ToByte(pixelColor.R & Mask0);
                        Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(NewRed, pixelColor.G, pixelColor.B);
                        image1.SetPixel(x1, y1, newColor);
                        pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x1, y1);

                        z++;
                        if (z == StringLenght)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NewRed = Convert.ToByte(pixelColor.R | Mask1);
                        Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(NewRed, pixelColor.G, pixelColor.B);
                        image1.SetPixel(x1, y1, newColor);
                        pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x1, y1);

                        z++;
                        if (z == StringLenght)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    if (sb[z] == '0')
                    {
                        NewGreen = Convert.ToByte(pixelColor.G & Mask0);
                        Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, NewGreen, pixelColor.B);
                        image1.SetPixel(x1, y1, newColor);
                        pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x1, y1);

                        z++;
                        if (z == StringLenght)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NewGreen = Convert.ToByte(pixelColor.G | Mask1);
                        Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, NewGreen, pixelColor.B);
                        image1.SetPixel(x1, y1, newColor);
                        pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x1, y1);

                        z++;
                        if (z == StringLenght)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (sb[z] == '0')
                    {
                        NewBlue = Convert.ToByte(pixelColor.B & Mask0);
                        Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, pixelColor.G, NewBlue);
                        image1.SetPixel(x1, y1, newColor);
                        pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x1, y1);

                        z++;
                        if (z == StringLenght)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NewBlue = Convert.ToByte(pixelColor.B | Mask1);
                        Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, pixelColor.G, NewBlue);
                        image1.SetPixel(x1, y1, newColor);
                        pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x1, y1);

                        z++;
                        if (z == StringLenght)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //string binary1 = Convert.ToString(pixelColor.R, 2);
                    //char last1 = binary1[binary1.Length - 1];
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Message embedded");
            //Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(NewRed, NewGreen, NewBlue);
            //image1.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
            // Set the PictureBox to display the image.
            //pictureBox1.Image = image1;

            // Display the pixel format in Label1.
            //label1.Text = "Pixel format: " + image1.PixelFormat.ToString();

        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error." +
                "Check the path to the image file.");
        }

        //pictureBox2.Image = image1;

        //Byte[] buf = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(RetreivedMessage.ToString());
        //Byte[] buf = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(RetreivedMessage.ToString());
        //string result = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buf);
        //String result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buf);
        //StringBuilder r2 = new StringBuilder();
        //foreach (Byte b in Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(FinalRetreivedMessage))
        //{
        //    r2.Append(Convert.ToString(b));
        // }
        //int v = 0;
        //for (int i = 0; i < FinalRetreivedMessage.Length; i++)
        //    {
        //     v = v * 2 + (FinalRetreivedMessage[i] == '0' ? 0 : 1);
        //    }
        //string result = v.ToString();


            // copy the string as UTF-8 bytes.
        //    byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[FinalRetreivedMessage.Length];
        //   for (int i = 0; i < FinalRetreivedMessage.Length; ++i)
        //   {
                //Debug.Assert( 0 <= utf8String[i] && utf8String[i] <= 255, "the char must be in byte's range");
        //        utf8Bytes[i] = (byte)FinalRetreivedMessage[i];
        //  }
            //Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);
            // utf8Bytes = new byte[]{1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0};
        //    string result1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);
            //string result1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
        //    UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
        //    string str = enc.GetString(utf8Bytes);
        //    Byte[] encodedBytes = enc.GetBytes(FinalRetreivedMessage);

        //    string message = encodedBytes.ToString();
        //   int count = FinalRetreivedMessage.Length / 8;
        //    var bollox = new byte[count];
        //    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        //        bollox[i] = Convert.ToByte(FinalRetreivedMessage.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2);

        //    var bollox1 = new byte[count];
            //for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                //bollox1[i] = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(FinalRetreivedMessage.Substring(i * 8, 8));

        //    string result2 = bollox.ToString();
        //   string result3 = enc.GetString(bollox);
        //    string result4 = System.Convert.ToString(bollox);
        //    string StringIWant = BitConverter.ToString(bollox);
        //    string result5 = BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes);
        //    string result6 = BitConverter.ToString(utf8Bytes);
        //    string result7 = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(FinalRetreivedMessage));
        //    string result8 = System.Convert.ToString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(FinalRetreivedMessage));
        //    string result9 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(FinalRetreivedMessage));
        //    string result10 = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(FinalRetreivedMessage));

    }`
```

Comment: at what point do you get the exception?

Comment: Impossible to say since we can't see the code that's actually throwing the exception.

Comment: if you step through the unit test with your debugger, you'll know what line throws the exception

Comment: you also aren't showing how you make the form, one issue is that you need to open the form for some things to work properly

Comment: at this line:  target.button2_Click(sender, e);

Comment: what's your code in button2_Click

Comment: I have added button2_click after the test function

Comment: Michael, sorry for my ignorance, could you correct me if i have made a mistake.

Comment: What values should i have for 'sender' and 'e' in this case?

Comment: Doesn't look like they matter, probably one the umpteen references you have in there that are decalred somewhere else. Starting with the one called key. if you make your first test, test foir textbox4 being an empty string you'll learn something.

Comment: So is it possible to manipulate the text of another textbox for this test. 'textbox4' is always set to blank no matter what i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Embed();
    }
public void Embed(string Embedkey, string EmbedMessage,Bitmap image3)
    {
     // embed message in image
    }


public void EmbedTest()
    {
        StegApp target = new StegApp(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string Embedkey = "123456"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string EmbedMessage = "test2"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        Bitmap image3 = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        image3 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\dt265\Project\Sky\sky-and-cloud.bmp",true);
        string a="123456",b="test2";
        target.Embed(Embedkey, EmbedMessage, image3);
        //Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
        if (Embedkey.Length > 6 || Embedkey.Length < 0)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Key is out of range");
        }
        //Assert.IsInstanceOfType(target.b1,typeof(byte[]));
        if(target.b1.Length != target.temp4.Length)
        {
            Assert.Fail("B1 array does not have the correct lenght");
        }
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(target.image1,typeof(Bitmap));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(target.sb,typeof(StringBuilder));
        if(target.sb.Length != target.tmp3.Length)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Issue with Stringbuilder sb. Lenght not equal to 'tmp3'!");
        }
        if(target.z != target.StringLenght)
        {
            Assert.Fail("z != StringLenght");
        }
        if (target.c != EmbedMessage.Length)
        {
            Assert.Fail("c is not the lenght of the Message!");
        }

    }
```